# Is it possible to spy on an object in which I have no control over it's creation, using mockk?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, spy, mockk, kotest

I have a Kotlin project using [kotest](https://kotest.io/) as my unit testing framework and [mockk](https://mockk.io/) to take care of my mocking requirements. I am new to all aspects of the Kotlin language and chosen testing libraries/frameworks.

I have a simple class in which a function creates an object which I want to spy on.

```kotlin
import java.net.URI

class MyClass {
    public fun doStuff() {
        val uri = URI("https://some-random-endpoint.com/get/some/stuff")
        // ...
        // ...use URI object to get some stuff
        // ...
    }
}
```

I would like to spy on the creation of the URI object to ensure it's passed the correct endpoint. Based off of [the documentation](https://mockk.io/#spy) I initially thought I could achieve my goal like this:

```kotlin
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.FunSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.mockk.spyk
import java.net.URI

class MyClassTest : FunSpec({
    test("doStuff should be targeting the correct endpoint") {
        val urlSpy = spyk<URI>()
        val myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
        myClass.doStuff()
        urlSpy.host shouldBe "some-random-endpoint.com"
        urlSpy.path shouldBe "/get/some/stuff"
    }
})
```

However, this fails as both `urlSpy.host` and `urlSpy.path` are `null`.

I've clearly misunderstood something. I suspect the under-the-hood magic I was hoping for is not associating my spy with the creation of the URI object in `MyClass.doStuff()`

If I replace my spy with a `mockk` then the creation of the URI object is mocked, as I would expect. However, a mock doesn't seem the correct object for me in this case... I don't want to mock the behaviour, I just want to verify the behaviour as it's coded.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe return URI from the method and check it instead?
It's not clear what you are actually trying to test here

Comment: Thanks @EvgenyBovykin. I did mention in my original post my intention for this very basic test: "I would like to spy on the creation of the URI object to ensure it's passed the correct endpoint"

Comment: There's a Constructor mock. IDK if that works for what you want https://mockk.io/#constructor-mocks . The `Spyk<URI>` bit won't spy on the constructor, it will only spy on the object itself, giving you an instance.`